# Double click on image how to redirect the product view page for mobiles

Tags: javascript, jquery

Upon double-clicking on image, how to redirect the product view page for mobiles?

This is my code but it's working only for single click:

```
$('.products-grid').find('a.product-image').click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         return true;
});
```

What do I have to add in that code for double click?

Comment: $('.products-grid').find('a.product-image').dblclick(function(e){ ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [jquery `dblclick()`](https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/) function.

```
$('.products-grid').find('a.product-image').dblclick(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         return true;
}
```

See the follow example:

```js
$('#myImg').dblclick(function(e){
     alert('double click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Double click on img</p>
<img src="https://blog.stackoverflow.com/images/wordpress/stackoverflow-logo-300.png" id="myImg"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would cache the element in a variable, then you can call on().

Like this,

```
var myElement = $('.products-grid').find('a.product-image');

myElement.on('dblclick', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     return true;
});
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't on() preferred over older event methods these days?

Comment: No change ...same thing happens ..single click is working but not double click